# After ffmpeg encode, AVPacket pts and dts is AV_NOPTS_VALUE

Tags: ffmpeg, encoder

I would like to ask a question about ffmpeg when i use encoder (x264).

this is my code :

```
int
FFVideoEncoder::init(AVCodecID codecId, int bitrate, int fps, int gopSize,
                     int width, int height, AVPixelFormat format) {
    release();

    const AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codecId);
    m_pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    m_pCodecCtx->width = width;
    m_pCodecCtx->height = height;
    m_pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = format;
    m_pCodecCtx->bit_rate = bitrate;
    m_pCodecCtx->thread_count = 5;
    m_pCodecCtx->max_b_frames = 0;
    m_pCodecCtx->gop_size = gopSize;

    m_pCodecCtx->time_base.num = 1;
    m_pCodecCtx->time_base.den = fps;

    //H.264
    if (m_pCodecCtx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264) {
//        av_dict_set(&opts, "preset", "slow", 0);
        av_dict_set(&m_pEncoderOpts, "preset", "superfast", 0);
        av_dict_set(&m_pEncoderOpts, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);

        m_pCodecCtx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
        m_pCodecCtx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }
    int ret = avcodec_open2(m_pCodecCtx, m_pCodecCtx->codec, &m_pEncoderOpts);
    if (ret == 0) {
        LOGI("open avcodec success!");
    } else {
        LOGE("open avcodec error!");
        return -1;
    }
    return ret;
}

int FFVideoEncoder::encode(const Frame &inFrame, AVPacket *outPacket) {
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
//    avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) frame, inFrame.getData(), AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, inFrame.getWidth(),
//                   inFrame.getHeight());
    av_image_fill_arrays(frame->data, frame->linesize, inFrame.getData(), m_pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                         inFrame.getWidth(), inFrame.getHeight(), 1);

    int ret = 0;
    ret = avcodec_send_frame(m_pCodecCtx, frame);
    if (ret != 0) {
        LOGE("send frame error! %s", av_err2str(ret));
    } else {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(m_pCodecCtx, outPacket);
        LOGI("extract data size = %d", m_pCodecCtx->extradata_size);
        if (ret != 0) {
            LOGE("receive packet error! %s", av_err2str(ret));
        }
    };
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    return ret;
}
```

I expect that the AVPacket  will carry the pts and dts about this frame.

but in fact, i only can get encoded frame data and size.

//====================================

except this question, i have another quesiont:

x264 docs say that "tune" opts can be set like film、animation and others. but i only can get a normal video when i set "zerolatency" params. When i set others opts, video's bitrate is very low.

Thanks your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for simple example to see if it works:

I believe you should set `frame->pts` beforehand.
Try this:
Set `frame->pts = framecount` before sending to `ret = avcodec_send_frame(m_pCodecCtx, frame)`

Add this `framecount` as a simple counter of frames you send for encode. Increases each time.
Hope that helps.

Comment: OMG. Thanks for your help.  actually i have every frame's pts. When i set the pts into the AVFrame, it works!!!