# How to get actual PTS and DTS after frame decoding with libavcodec of FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, c++, decoding

C++, FFmpeg, libavcodec, video frames decoding.

To parse data from the network and split it into frames, I use the `av_parser_parse2(_parser, _context, &_packet_encoded_frame->data, &_packet_encoded_frame->size, data, data_size, pts ? pts : AV_NOPTS_VALUE, dts ? dts : AV_NOPTS_VALUE, 0)` function to which I pass non-zero values PTS and DTS as inputs.

Next, I use the `avcodec_send_packet(_context, _packet_encoded_frame)` and `avcodec_receive_frame(_context, _frame)` functions to decode the frames.

Why do I ALWAYS have PTS(_frame->pts) and DTS(_frame->pkt_dts) equal to AV_NOPTS_VALUE after SUCCESSFUL frame decoding? How can I get the actual PTS and DTS values of that frame after decoding a frame? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47549940/after-ffmpeg-encode-avpacket-pts-and-dts-is-av-nopts-value

Comment: This question is about the encoder, but I'm interested in the decoder. There it was required to set the PTS values for the incoming encoded frame in order to get them for the outgoing packet. By analogy, I thought that I set the incoming PTS values in the av_parser_parse2 function, but do not receive them for the outgoing decoded frame. Perhaps I need to set the incoming PTS values in some other place, but then where and how can I calculate these values for each frame, if it is the av_parser_parse2 function that is engaged in framing?

Comment: How about `frame->pkt_dts` and `frame->best_effort_timestamp`?

Comment: _frame->pts, _frame->pkt_dts and _frame->best_effort_timestamp equal to AV_NOPTS_VALUE

Comment: "Parse data from the network" is not enough information for answering your question. As far as I know, the PTS and DTS are coming from the container, and not from the "elementary stream". (`pts` and `dts` are inputs to `av_parser_parse2`). What is the video container / protocol?

Comment: @Rotem PTS and DTS are coming from PES packet of MPEG TS

Comment: Right, the PTS and DTS are coming from the container/"transport stream", in your case, from the  MPEG TS (transport stream). I think we don't suppose to use `av_parser_parse2` when there is a container or transport stream. In the examples I saw, `av_parser_parse2` is only used when decoding "elementary stream" (when there is no Demuxer).

Comment: @Rotem MPEG TS carries PES packets. PES packets carry elementary streams. I parse the PES packet myself and send its payload (actually an elementary stream) to the av_parser_parse2 function. Is it wrong?
I thought that for this purpose it is possible to pass the PTS and DTS values as input parameters to the av_parser_parse2 function in order to associate elementary streams with these values. I'm wrong?
By the way, the entire decoding process is successful, except that the decoded frames are not associated with PTS and DTS in any way.

Comment: I am sure that it's possible. I don't have enough experience with the C interface of FFmpeg for answering. In the decoding code samples I didn't see usage of `av_parser_parse2` when the video is in a container.